# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughOutputFormat

Tags: hive, hbase, apache-spark, shark-sql

I have followed [this](http://www.abcn.net/2014/04/install-shark-on-cdh5-hadoop2-spark.html) link for installing shark on CDH5. I have installed it but as it also mentioned on the above block:-

```
This -skipRddReload is only needed when you have some table with hive/hbase mapping, because of some issus in PassthroughOutputFormat by hive hbase handler.

the error message is something like:
"Property value must not be null"
or
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughOutputFormat"
```

I have created an external table in hive to access Hbase table and when i tried shark with  `-skipRddReload` ,shark gets started but when i tred to access the same external table within shark getting error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughOutputFormat
```

Is there any solution to get rid of this ?

**EDIT**

Hbase to hive with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (key string,LPID STRING,Value int,ts1 STRING,ts2 STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:LPID,cf1:Value,cf1:ts1,cf1:ts2") 
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "abc");
```

This abc i wanted to access in shark,any solution ?

Comment: What's your table definition? Are you using any serdes?

Comment: Make sure that the hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is properly linked in both Shark as well as CDH. I'm not aware of how Cloudera packages it, but it will be most probably in `cdh/lib/hive/lib`. Also make sure that it's present in all the worker nodes too..